# How to remove (unlink) all the grease pencil layers?

Tags: edit-mode, grease-pencil

I have plenty of *grease pencil* sketches in my blend file. Is it possible to remove all of them very fast?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short answer:** 
Yes!

Press <kbd>N</kbd>, go to *Grease Pencil* and uncheck the checkbox:

[image]

This will hide all grease pencil sketches, while retaining the information in case you want your sketches back at a later time.

**Long answer:** 
In the *Viewport* press <kbd>N</kbd> and go to the *Grease Pencil* portion of the menu on the right.

[image]

There are several ways to remove a grease pencil sketch, you can just hide the grease pencil (the checkbox), you can delete a frame, you can delete a layer (the "X"), or you can hide a layer (the eye).
You can use the <kbd>RMB</kbd> or use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to get the grease eraser. Use the <kbd>LMB</kbd> (or <kbd>RMB</kbd> depending on the method) to erase, and the <kbd>MMB</kbd> to change the size of the brush.

Comment: Uncheck the 'check box'. Simple and effective :). Thanks a lot NoviceInDisguise Graphics!

Comment: I'm not able to find the Grease Pencil menu in blender 3.0. It may have been moved

Answer (score 4):

You could also run a script to remove the layers after saving the .blend the sketches should be removed.

```
import bpy

for g in bpy.data.grease_pencil:
    for l in g.layers:
        g.layers.remove(l)
```

Comment: this seems to wreck the grease pencil for futrher drawing on the same blender session (not even opening another file will restore the funcitonality)